# I need to create a navigation menu for one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a navigation menu for a page I'm making and I would like to change the active link when someone clicks on it. I already have styles on the active link but I dont know how to make it change. Having it change when someone hovers over it would also be great. Javascript is alright. Thank you.

Menu

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-3 columns">
        <a class="logo" href="/">Saul Designs</a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-7 columns">
        <nav class="main-nav show-for-large-up">
            <ul>
<!-- below this is what i need to have change-->

                                    <li><a class="active" href="#start">START</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#work" >WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>

    <!-- and above this -->
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <div class="normal-button alternate show-for-large-up">
            <a href="mailto:example@me.com">HIRE ME</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767161/keep-link-active-after-clicked-using-same-page-anchors

Answer (score 0):

You can use the anchor for styling stuff in css3. The Problem here is that you have to specify matching ids to every anchor you have.

So you have to write:

```
<li><a id="start" href="#start">START</a></li>
<li><a id="about" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a id="work" href="#work" >WORK</a></li>
<li><a id="contact" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

Then you have to add 4 stylerules, too:

```
#start:target, #about:target, #work:target, #contact:target{
    background:#555; /* or as you want... */
}
```

This way it should work without any additional javascript.
I don't like this way because you have to specify every id and you are polluting the css-space. But I don't know another way using only html and css.